# Auth::check is not working in my laravel 9 dont know why

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

i have made 2 controllers login and logout .. my login controller is working fine and im logged in successfully but when im log out it shows the method user not log in . dont know whats going on Here is my Login Controller:

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        // attempt to authenticate the user
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            // create an access token for the authenticated user
            $user = User::find(Auth::id());
            $token = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;

            return response()->json(['access_token' => $token, 'user' => Auth::user()]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
    }
```

**its working perfectly fine and my access token is generating . Im using laravel passport for generating a token here is my logout method:**

```
 public function logout(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        // Get the current user's ID
        $userId = Auth::id();

        // Delete the specific user's access token
        AccessToken::where('user_id', $userId)->update(['revoked' => true]);

        // Log the user out of the application
        Auth::logout();

        // Return a JSON response with a success message and a 200 status code
        return response()->json('Logged out successfully', 200);
    }
    else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User not logged in']);
    }
}
```

**Dont know what am i doing wrong its not entering in if condition . any help would be appreciated. Thanks**

I have tried everything in my exposure but in vain

Comment: `dd(Auth::user())` before `Auth::check()` and see the result , user data is there or not.

Comment: did you send the correct token to logout api ? if necessary you can test it using postman

Comment: @BhargavChudasama yes i checked and user data is there

Comment: so use `Auth::user()` instead of `Auth::check()` and check

Comment: @BhargavChudasama already done that same issue

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that the logout route is using the `auth:api` middleware
- Make sure that you're sending the token as bearer token in request header

Comment: im sending the token with the header but whenever i add auth api it shows me im unauthorized

Comment: how do you send the token?

Comment: im including the access token in the request header

Comment: sending it like this  'Authorization: Bearer $token' ?
or in Postman you can also use the authorization header and choose Bearer Token